# How to stop xargs from badly merging output from multiple processes?

Tags: process, io, xargs, parallelism

I'm using `xargs` with the option `--max-args=0` (alternatively `-P 0`).

However, the output of the processes is merged into the `stdout` stream without regard for proper line separation. So I'll often end up with lines such as:

```
<start-of-line-1><line-2><end-of-line-1>
```

As I'm using `egrep` with `^` in my pattern on the whole `xargs` output this is messing up my result.

Is there some way to force `xargs` to write the process outputs in order (any order, as long as the output of one process is contiguous)?

Or some other solution?

**Edit:** more details about the use case:

I want to download and parse web pages from different hosts. As every page takes about a second to load and there are a few dozen pages I want to parallelize the requests.

My command has the following form:

```
echo -n $IPs | xargs --max-args=1 -I {} --delimiter ' ' --max-procs=0 \
wget -q -O- http://{}/somepage.html | egrep --count '^string'
```

I use bash and not something like Perl because the host IPs (the $IPs variable) and some other data comes from an included bash file.

Comment: Can you can a more complete example to your question? It is not clear how or why you are currently using `xargs`.

Comment: The solution to this will be tough, one need to use different file descriptors for stdout's of each process and use a small server to collect the lines. `xargs` doesn't seem to provide such a feature.

Comment: @Caleb There you go, hope this helps :-)

Comment: Definitely not a lightweight solution, but maybe you could use `make`'s jobs feature, I think `make` merges output lines properly.

Comment: does adding the `--line-buffered` flag to `egrep` help

Comment: @iruvar No. The problem is due to non-atomic writes: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Non-atomic_writes_with_xargs_-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
echo -n $IPs | xargs --max-args=1 -I {} --delimiter ' ' --max-procs=0 \
  sh -c "wget -q -O- 'http://{}/somepage.html' | egrep --count '^string'" | \
  { NUM=0; while read i; do NUM=$(($NUM + $i)); done; echo $NUM; }
```

The idea here is to make separate counts and sum these at the end.
Might fail if the separate counts are big enough to be mixed, but it should not be the case.

Answer (score 18):

GNU Parallel is specifcally designed to solve this problem:

```
echo -n $IPs | parallel -d ' ' -j0 wget -q -O- http://{}/somepage.html | egrep --count '^string'
```

If your IPs are in a file it is even prettier:

```
cat IPs | parallel -j0 wget -q -O- http://{}/somepage.html | egrep --count '^string'
```

To learn more watch the intro video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: Nice tool! Also, I'm betting that someone will tell you that cat is useless very soon.

Comment: I know. But I find it easier to read, and I usually work on 48 core machines, so the few extra clock cycles for one of the idle cores has yet to be a problem.

Comment: parallel would be perfect for the job if it was in the Debian repositories.

Comment: @Legate Debian includes the `parallel` command from [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/), which is sufficient here: `parallel -j99 -i sh -c 'wget -q -O- http://{}/somepage.html | egrep -c "^string"' -- $IPs`

Comment: @Legate checkout https://build.opensuse.org/package/binaries?package=parallel&project=home%3Atange&repository=Debian_5.0 for a .deb file and http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=518696 for the bug to push.

Comment: @Giles the `parallel` in moreutils is not GNU Parallel - which is the reason you need to do the `-i sh -c` circus.

Comment: @Ole Thanks for the links. I read through the bug report, hopefully `parallel` will make it into the repositories soon. Unfortunately, I won't be able to use the deb from the OpenSUSE Build Service, as introducing a third-party package on the machine I need this on is not desirable.

Comment: for me moreutils parallel didn't protect from mixing stdout, I had to install GNU version.